# What are the types of react-hook-form methods?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/ts/) and I want to have certain parts of the form in an extra component. Therfore I need to pass down some methods. What are the correct `typescript types` of the methods: `register, control, setValue, watch` ?

[Example Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-resolver-forked-dp8hw)

```
interface INameInput {
  register: any;
  setValue: any;
  watch: any;
  control: any;
}

const NameInput: React.FC<INameInput> = (props: INameInput) => {
  const { register, control, setValue, watch } = props;

  return (
    <>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input name="firstName" ref={register} />

        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input name="lastName" ref={register} />
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const { register, control, setValue, watch} = useForm<FormValues>();

  return (
      <form >
        <NameInput 
           register={register} 
           control={control} 
           setValue={setValue} 
           watch={watch} 
        />
      </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked for me: register: ReturnType<typeof useForm>['register'];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a page which contains the list of exported Types

https://react-hook-form.com/ts

I think you are after the following type

https://react-hook-form.com/ts#UseFormMethods

eg:

```
UseFormMethods['register']
```